# SetServiceStatus always giving "invalid current state 0"

Tags: .net, windows, service, version-control

I have a service running on Windows Server 2012 written in VB.NET targeting .NET 4.5.2

Whenever I call SetServiceStatus I get "service has reported an invalid current state 0". Not causing me a huge problem and the service continues to function OK, but I assume the SCM can close the service if it doesn't report running correctly.

When I start the service I get 2 errors in the log, I assume for the PENDING and RUNNING calls :

```
Public Enum ServiceState As UInteger
    SERVICE_STOPPED = 1
    SERVICE_START_PENDING = 2
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 3
    SERVICE_RUNNING = 4
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 5
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 6
    SERVICE_PAUSED = 7
End Enum

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure ServiceStatus
    Public dwServiceType As Long
    Public dwCurrentState As UInteger
    Public dwControlsAccepted As Long
    Public dwWin32ExitCode As Long
    Public dwServiceSpecificExitCode As Long
    Public dwCheckPoint As Long
    Public dwWaitHint As Long
End Structure

Public Class myService
    Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    Declare Auto Function SetServiceStatus Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByRef serviceStatus As ServiceStatus) As Boolean

    Private _serviceStatus As ServiceStatus

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        _serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING
        SetServiceStatus(Me.ServiceHandle, _serviceStatus)


        _serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING
        SetServiceStatus(Me.ServiceHandle, _serviceStatus)

    End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()

        _serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED
        SetServiceStatus(Me.ServiceHandle, _serviceStatus)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm believe you will need to fill out all the fields of the structure, not just `.dwCurrentState`.  But in any case, it is my understanding that `ServiceBase` will do that for you.  You shouldn't need to call `SetServiceStatus` yourself.

Comment: IMO the problem here "Managed Code" (VB .NET) vs. "Unmanged Code" (Windows API / external DLL). See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default manual for VB.Net from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx you will recognize, that they converted from older VB6 version which has the type of `LONG` (32Bit int) but now it should be called `Integer` (32 Bit int).

Try the following structure

```
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure ServiceStatus
    Public dwServiceType As Integer
    Public dwCurrentState As ServiceStateEnum
    Public dwControlsAccepted As Integer
    Public dwWin32ExitCode As Integer
    Public dwServiceSpecificExitCode As Integer
    Public dwCheckPoint As Integer
    Public dwWaitHint As Integer
End Structure
```